# WP7 XNA: simple photo album

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm beginner in XNA. How can I do simple photo album with flipping images on XNA?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have experience with programming in general, or are you new to all of it as a whole?

A book I highly recommend is Learning XNA 4.0 by Aaron Reed, which you can find [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920013709) or on Amazon (for much cheaper). Chapter 13 discusses HLSL basics and specifically uses the example of an image and the potential for an image gallery using interesting, 3D technologies to display and run them in XNA.

However, I'd advise you to check out this link: [Photo Album - App Hub Forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/9017/47119.aspx)

It has an interesting discussion relevant to your topic.

Let me know if I can be of any more help!

Comment: I know how to write album on silverlight. But now I interested in XNA. Thanks for book.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SpriteBatch`. Look at the [2D Graphics](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/graphics_2d) sample on App Hub for an example.

(This kind of application may be better suited to Silverlight.)

Comment: +1 for SpriteBatch. You could mention he will have to implement transitions and the like himself though.